# Snakemake shell strange execution order

Tags: bash, shell, snakemake

I'm trying to download file via FTP and process it after.
For example rule like this

```
rule all:
    output:
        test_input = "ref/" + test_file
    shell:
        """        
            ftp -ni {test_domain} <<-EOF 1> log.txt 2> log.txt
                user anonymous " "
                lcd ref
                cd {test_path}
                get {test_file}
                # quit
            EOF
            ls
        """
```

Here is two problems.
First: In current code `ls` will be executed on ftp server side.
Second: If I uncomment `quit` - none of commands I add after `EOF` will ever be executed. Even in regular shell script it works fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm guessing the EOF isn't preceded by literal tabs, and so the shell doesn't see it. Unfortunately, Stack Overflow converts tabs to spaces on rendering, but the source of your question appears to have spaces too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the limit string is missed at the end of the here-doc, [as mentioned by @tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69114115/snakemake-shell-strange-execution-order#comment122155995_69114115). This causes the `ls` to be executed on the server through ftp and the `quit` command to stop further execution.

Snakemake will not strip leading whitespace in the string literal under the shell directive. To get your script working as expected, you could either remove leading whitespace in your `shell` directive or be sure that any leading whitespace in the here-doc are only literal tabs.

Here's an updated script that produces the expected output for me:

```
rule all:
    output:
        test_input = "ref/" + test_file
    shell:
        """
ftp -ni {test_domain} <<EOF 1> log.txt 2> log.txt
user anonymous " "
lcd ref
cd {test_path}
get {test_file}
quit
EOF
ls
"""
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to this because I've had the same issue and stumbled upon this thread from a Google search. You can also wrap the multiline string in the shell directive in a dedenting function like this:

```
import textwrap

rule all:
    output:
        test_input = "ref/" + test_file
    shell:
        textwrap.dedent("""        
            ftp -ni {test_domain} <<-EOF 1> log.txt 2> log.txt
                user anonymous " "
                lcd ref
                cd {test_path}
                get {test_file}
                # quit
            EOF
            ls
        """)
```

I think this is a much more elegant (and nicer looking) solution then to remove the indentation in the script.